# Mixing fonts in Emacs

Tags: emacs, fonts

Is is possible to get Emacs show different parts of file with different fonts? As a specific problem, I would like to be able to render following small XML file otherwise normally but the 'text' part inside 'example' elements with different font and font size.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <example>text</example>
</root>
```

If it makes any difference I have GTK+ Version 2.22.0 of GNU Emacs 23.1.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Assuming you're using something like [nxhtml-mode](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html) (which uses `mumamo` or "multiple major modes mode"), you should be able to do `M-x customize-group mumamo [RET]`, find the font face you want to customize, and go at it. It'll place a block of code in your `~/.emacs` that you can look at if you'd like to tweak it by hand.

Comment: I had little bit of trouble to get this working, but finally nailed it. Thanks for pointing to right direction.

Comment: No problem! It can be frustrating to figure out what face is what and how to customize things -- especially with nxhtml/mumamo. At least it's doable, though :)